# Need to Add new property to all the labels expect the label name not starts like 'IA_' in neo4j cypher

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I want to add new property for all lables except the lable name starts with 'x'

I have tried the below cyper query but it's failing.

```
MATCH (n)
WITH DISTINCT labels(n) AS label
UNWIND label AS names
WITH names AS candidate
WHERE candidate =~ '^(.?$|[^I].+|I[^A].*)*'
CALL apoc.create.setProperty(labels(candidate),'link','')
    YIELD node
    return node
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add properties to labels. You can only add properties to nodes that have certain labels.

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE NONE( label IN labels(n) WHERE label STARTS WITH ‘IA_’ )
SET n.myProperty = myValue
```

adds a property to nodes not having a label starting with IA_